# Audio Quality Assessment

Tags: speech-processing, music, audio-processing, perceived-quality

I need an algorithm to assess the quality of a given audio. The task, is considered to be no-reference. Can anyone help me whether there is any method for quality assessment of any given audio?

**edit1:**
Note that I do not want to just classify them to good/bad (or similarly high/low quality). I need to give a score(similar to MOS) to show how much good/bad is the given audio based on human auditory system (human perception).

**edit2:**
I need to describe the above question more, because some people have marked it as to be duplicate. See, I need to predict the subjective score. This question was not asked at StackExcahnge, before. In [Analyzing the quality of a music track](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48027/analyzing-the-quality-of-a-music-track) a different question has been asked. As its author (@robert-lemiesz) has explained in the 3rd comment of the main post, **he was *not* looking for predicting subjective score**. But, I am looking for predicting subjective score. Please, remove your vote from this post of being duplicate and kindly help me to get to the correct answer.

Comment: basically, there's no such thing as "objective" audio quality. Is a crystal-clean recording of some synthesizer-driven pop music "better" in quality than the muddy, distorted original recording of Jimi Hendrix' All Along The Watchtower?

Comment: Can you post two representative examples of two tracks, one which would have to be given the tag "low quality" and one which would have to be given the tag "high quality"? You may be able to train a model given specific characteristics to perform the filtering you are after with some accuracy.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your comments. Actually, as I described in the edit of the post, I do not want to just classify the audio into good/bad quality. I need to give a score(similar to MOS) to show how much good/bad is the audio.

Comment: Is it speech or is it music, or something else?

Comment: Dear @olli-niemitalo , I am looking for a general solution. Anyway, please explain if you know any solution which works for special category(e.g. only for music).

Comment: what is the *"quality"* being assessed?  what does *"high quality"* or "*low quality*" mean?  how can you describe this meaning without a reference signal?

Comment: @robert-bristow-johnson , our auditory system as humankind is capable to rate different audios without giving the reference. We may give an audio a high score if practically we do not feel any distortion in that. On the contrary, we will give low score if we feel there is a problem with the audio. It is exactly the perception!

Comment: @Quasar nothing really changes that this quality perception is extremely subjective. Your edits sadly don't change that you're trying to predict subjective perception, and you won't be able to do that without "training" your algorithm with exactly the subject. I think my example of muddy electric bass sound and voice vs overly crisp pop synthesizer and autotune is pretty good: One of both is unpleasant to my ears, but I know a lot of people that would see it exactly the other way around.

Comment: and I think @Fat32's answer already answers pretty much exactly the point you describe in your second edit.

Comment: Dear @marcus-müller , I think you are stuck to the most difficult understanding of my question. When talking about the perceived audio quality, we mainly try to rate the quality if the audio has good quality considering the presence of artifacts and distortions. Any typical person can do this job, even he/she does know what is the reason of that distortion but can understand it. Notice that while talking about audio quality assessment we are not talking about psychological aspects and favorites of each person that you are concerning about!

Comment: *there's no such thing as an objective distortion*. Really. Distortion is in *many* forms of music part of the music. Just let me give you two examples: [example of compressed dynamic range in a high-quality piece of audio. This is how it's supposed to sound (Jimi Hendrix – All along the Watchtower)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLV4_xaYynY) || [Autotune in Hip Hop music, which amounts to strong artifacts as you'd get them in low-rate linear prediction speech compression. This is how it's supposed to sound. (Kanye West – Amazing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Amazingkanye.ogg).

Comment: More examples: the usual 1970's – 1980's synth pop used [*flanging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanging#Timeline) (just look at the list of examples!) a lot, an effect you get when you have two tones in an audio signal and a nonlinearity in your system. This is absolutely *core inventory* of pop music audio engineering. Objectively, it's a distortion. Subjectively, it's a feature of the music. In other music, it would be a sign  of a broken recording amplifier or something, in the songs that use it, it's central to the "feeling" of that song.

Comment: Don't get me started on so-called "8-bit music" (which has about nothing to do with 8 bits, but that's a different rant for a different day), about the typical metal "wall of sound", about how you're supposed to assess the quality of all the genres that are considered under what is called "Lo-Fi"; let me not even mention Grunge, or Jazz produced with Rock-typical production like e.g. Doldinger. There's exquisitely crisply produced *drone*, a genre known for its oscillating, *extremely slowly changing* sounds, rhythms in the single-digit BPM, as if someone forgot to unplug his e-guitar.

Comment: I can go on for hours. Have you listened to Shostakovich? That's orchestral music from the early 20th century. Guess what, industrialization was a main theme, and so is the sound of his compositions: Grinding, often leaving the range of "pleasant" and undistorted sounds the instruments make. Oh, and hip hop voice productions in general tend to use *very* anti-pop techniques to make vocals sound "flat". In another genre, that would be an indication of badly recorded audio!

Comment: Another typical example is gain pumping (1980's, early 1990's hip hop, for example), which would normally be an indication of someone not standing in constant distance to a microphone, or an amplifier having severe heat or power supply problems.

Comment: Notice that all these rants refer to *some kind of aesthetically relevant quality of sound, especially music*. Now, intelligibility of voice is a different thing, but even here, distortion can help or can do damage, and it depends on the auditory expectations of the listener and the quality of the speaker which does which. (And Olli has written a pretty good answer about that, already.)

Answer (score 3):

Audio quality assessment is one of the most critical pieces of audio coding and enhancing applications. The task requires an accurate and objective (mathematical) modeling of human auditory system including its **subjective virtues**.

However, the task of subjective quality assessment is one of the most complex problems to be attacked on Earth. Currently all available models mostly deal with basic things like quantization, SNR, bandwidth, distortion, masking, delay, echo, frequency response, etc... Achievements are like, detecting speech or music, recognition of musical instruments and acoustical environments, determination of the musical genre etc.

Theoretical studies for modeling an accurate human auditory system are carried out at audio signal processing laboratoaries around the world for designing automated audio compression algorithms to optimize the bitrate of audio based on the computed (percepted) audio quality.

Comment: Thanks @fat32 . So, you mean, so far, there is no way to assess the quality of any given audio in a way that its result would have high correlation coefficient with human opinion score?

Comment: @Quasar I don't say *there is no way*; there may be some but exremely complex. The issue **subjectivity** is beyond the reach of compemporary science and engineering... I hope this suffices to describe the seriousness of the problem ;-)

Comment: Dear @fat32 , I understand how complex it is. But, I was wondering if there has been any way proposed for this issue, yet?

Comment: @Quasar you can find such a model from Fraunhofer Institute. Send them a mail for asking an evaluation copy of the human hearing system model...

Answer (score 1):

By quality, one might mean intelligibility, which may be reduced by noise and other signal degradation. This kind of assumes that there is a reference signal that gets degraded, although the reference signal is not available.

One idea is to measure Gaussianity of the signal. From the abstract of *Ganesh R. Naik & Dinesh K. Kumar (2011) [**Improving the quality of the audio sources using Gaussianity reduction technique**](https://doi.org/10.1080/00207217.2010.538896), International Journal of Electronics, 98:7, 949-959*:

> Background signals are a result of the inferential summation of large
>   number of sources, while the foreground signals are a result of
>   limited number of sources. This makes the statistical properties of
>   the signal very different.

This is related to summing of independent signals and the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). Likewise, reverb and echos make the audio less intelligible, and those also make the signal's distribution more Gaussian if the original signal is not correlated with itself much over such long time lags.

Distortion (signal clipping) will reduce Gaussianity, which may be a problem with this approach. Then again distortion may actually improve (speech) intelligibility.