# How to measure quality of an audio/music recording compared to the original

Tags: matlab, audio, waveform-similarity

I have 3 wav files:

1. The original recording of a viola note
2. A noisy re-recording of the original clip
3. A different noisy re-recording of the original clip

I'm looking for a way to show which of the two noisy re-recordings is better than the other, and/or more similar to the original.

I can plot the time-domain waveforms and spectrograms which show that the signals are vaguely similar, but ideally I could find a measurement that gives me a single number - something like "recording 1 = 35% quality, recording 2 = 63% quality". I've tried "corcoeff".

In the image below, the original is in blue, the decent recording is in green, and the bad one is in red.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Audio Quality Assessment](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/audio-quality-assessment)

Comment: Maybe you could compare [SNRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) of the audio signals

Comment: There are no actual answers in the above question.